# Определение движения телефона в пространстве

Tags: c#, android, алгоритм, unity3d, unity3d-faq

Задача состоит в отслеживании движения телефона в пространстве, а именно в отслеживании определенных "жестов":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. вертикальные рывки вверх или вниз
2. горизонтальные рывки вправо-влево
3. повороты вокруг вертикальной оси на N градусов

Общая проблема состоит в том, что нужен именно рывок - т.е. движение на относительно большое расстояние (или угол) за малое время. И поэтому нужно как-то отфильтровывать плавное перемещение, трясущиеся руки и т.п.

В качестве исходных данных я обладаю показаниями акселерометра.

Какие существуют алгоритмы для решения подобной задачи? Возможно уже где-то есть готовые примеры. Желательно все это на C# под Unity, но сойдет и любой другой язык или просто алгоритм.

Comment: Возможно, поможет [этот материал](https://habrahabr.ru/company/badoo/blog/304488/). Здесь на примере Rx, но алгоритм тот же.

Answer (score 7):

Я сам таким не занимался, но то как я вижу решение опишу:

Нужно написать самому скрипт. В принципе, ничего критически сложного.
Для начала узнай что такое [Fifo](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)

1. Внутри FixedUpate
   Считываешь последние показания в Input.Acceleration во всех областях на некоем промежутке времени и записываешь в Fifo. Пусть для начала Fifo будет размеров гдето в 30 ячеек. Потом опытным путем подберешь оптимальный размер Fifo
2. в Upate сравниваешь среднее значение по всему Fifo. Если оно не больше чем некий макс уровень(подбирается опытным путем) - то это просто тряска рук. Иначе...
3. Выясняешь какой из жестов был сделан. Соответственно проходишь по самой большой разнице по соответствующей оси(а в Fifo записываются все 3 оси) с помощью LINQ запроса и генерируешь некий ивент на который подписываешь нужные методы.... ну или же напряму делаешь вызов метода :)

PS: повторюсь, я сам такого не делал. Но если бы делал, то в первую очередь действовал по даному описанию. А потом уже если бы не вышло искал бы другие варианты.

Вряд ли готовые решения найдешь. А если и найдешь - то вряд ли толковые. Я даже свайпы сам писал когда-то, потому что свайпы что нашел в инете были не фонтан... А это,ведь, достаточно тривиальная задача...

---

Апдейт:

> У него оказалась проблема, что после рывка, к примеру по направлению
>   оси Х, "отлавливается" сперва событие движения вдоль этой оси, а потом
>   против.

Введи еще одну булевую переменную-флаг ReadyForNextAction. При вызове метода ставь ReadyForNextAction = false;

И, собственно, просто делай игнорирование всех движений через этот флаг пока снова не устаканится акселерометр до "спокойного уровня" по **всему фифо**. Снова же, возможно прийдется немного править количество ячеек фифо в большую сторону, скорей всего...Но должно пофиксится.

Если получишь хороший результат - кидай код сюда, для следующих поколений, так сказать)

Comment: Я попробовал этот метод. У него оказалась проблема, что после рывка, к примеру по направлению оси Х, "отлавливается" сперва событие движения вдоль этой оси, а потом против. Происходит это из-за торможения, во время которого ускорение такое же по величине но с другим знаком. Это частично решается значительным увеличением длинны fifo, частично дополнительной логикой подсчета количества шагов, сильно отличающихся от среднего, но по итогам у меня не получилось обеспечить адекватную точность отсеивания этого эффекта (где-то один раз из пяти он проскакивает)

Comment: Апдейтонул сам ответ.

Comment: А не получится ли при игнорировании всех движений пока не устаканится такая ситуация, что не будет отлавливаться рывок, к примеру, вниз, который следует моментально за рывком вверх?

Comment: Именно так и получится. Если рывок за рывком.

Comment: Я не виду другого варианта. Или же следить за каждым рывком во все стороны, или же игнорировать рывок назад. Как возможно отличить рывок назад от возврата назад програмно? Или же.. Как бы вы, как человек, отличили одно от другого стоя сбоку так что бы наверника? Никак? Вот и програмно тоже никак :)

Comment: Ну а если, все же, придумаешь как возможно отличить один тип движения(правильный) от другого(от движения "назад") стоя сбоку - я подправлю тебе алгоритм :) Но подозреваю что не сможешь :) Невозможно через телефон добится однозначного отличия одного движения от другого. Мы не можем читать намерения человека, который держит телефон.

Comment: Мне тут посоветовали проделать все то же самое, основываясь на том, что ускорение - это вторая производная от расстояния. И за счет этого заполнять очередь пройденным расстоянием и триггерить события при перемещении на определенное минимальное расстояние. Данный подход должен эту проблему решить

Comment: Допустим. А как это спасет? Ведь независимо от того на что ориентироватся на минимальное ускорение или минимальное растояние - движения будут восприниматся все равно в любую сторону... Ну в любом случае не забудь скинуть код)

Comment: Типа погрешность ниже при использовании расстояния. Больше вероятность того, что после рывка сохранится среднее значение очереди. Так же есть вариант полностью отказаться от очереди и смотреть расстояние, пройденное за кадр обновления. Для этого нужно помнить текущую скорость движения вдоль нужной оси.

Comment: Чем закончилось-то? Как прошли успехи? Скриптом с общественностью поделишся?

Comment: В условии задачи ясно сказано, что требуется отслеживать амплитуду перемещения (читаем: "... движение на относительно большое расстояние"). В данном решении не делается никаких попыток анализировать амплитуду пепемещений (т.е. время между ускорениями). Как это может соответствовать условию задачи?

Comment: @AnT если это считать в FixedUpdate то про это не нужно думать. Если же кидать в Update - то просто нужно учитывать Time.Delta - вобщем, проблем с этим в принципе не должно возникать никаких.