# Создать имитацию коробки с кубиком прикрепленной к экрану мобильного в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот представьте себе что у вас в руках коробка. Одна из сторон - стекло (экран телефона)

Когда вы поворачиваете телефон -- кубик внутри скатывается под силой притяжения. Когда вы трясете телефон -- кубик внутри прыгает отскакивая от сторон коробки.
Как это же самое реализовать на юнити?

Итак задачи:

**1. [СДЕЛАНО] Прикрепить "коробку" с плейнов к экрану телефона.**

Это просто -- нужно всего лишь поместить плейны с коллайдерами внутрь обьекта камеры.

**2. [СДЕЛАНО]  Скейлить коробку под размер экрана телефона.**

Как оказалось на практике, это совсем не тривиальная задача. Я правильно настроил камеру (видит на 7 метров вдаль, пол коробки находится в 6 метрах).
Попробовал найти множитель

```
float mult = Mathf.Sqrt(30 * 30 + 5 * 5) * multiplier;
//30 - размер половины поля камеры(field of view)
//5 - растояние от камеры до верхней точки стенок "коробки". Фактически, линия взора камеры должна упиратся в даную точку.
// multiplier - по логике должен был подбиратся вручную
float w = (float)Screen.width / 2 * mult;
float h = (float)Screen.height / 2 * mult;
```

а потом делать сдвиги стенок используя w и h.
но по факту нихрена не вышло =(

UPD: оказалось что высота экрана не меняется, потому стенки вертикально раздвигать не нужно

**3. [ПРОБЛЕМА] Улавливать поворот телефона и поворачивать камеру в соответствии с ним**

Решается довольно простым кодом:

```
this.transform.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
```

Но как автоматически определять направление "пола" в реальном мире? Он должен быть там, где задняя стенка телефона когда тот лежит на столе.
Как возможно узнать даный угол что бы внести поправку?

Проблема еще в том, что реакция довольно медленная. Возможно, лучше будет сначала узнать где находится земля через гироскоп, а потом уже повороты телефона улавливать через акселерометр...
Есть у кого идеи?

**4. [ПРОБЛЕМА] Улавливать тряску телефона и трясти камеру в соответствии с ним**
Тряску, в теории, нужно определять так как я описывал сдесь:
[Определение движения телефона в пространстве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572837/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5/574156#574156)

Но, все же, может, кто посоветует более оптимальный вариант для даного случая.