# Система частиц в AR приложении

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Я хочу сделать пыль, которая будет летать вокруг нашей AR камеры. Но проблема заключается в том, что AR камера является центром мировой системы координат и, соответственно, система частиц передвигается и поворачивается вместе с камерой, даже когда они не являются к ней дочерними. Как мне исправить данную проблему и сделать свободный полет частиц в воздухе?

Answer (score 1):

Отслеживать движение камеры в пространстве и двигать AR камеру в ней. (ну или наоборот - пыль относительно камеры)

На самом деле задача реально сложная т.к. всех датчиков телефона для этого будет недостаточно что бы сделать это с высокой точностью.

Что бы ты понимал на сколько это сложная задача - первый HTC Vive работает с двумя док-станциями которые помогают определить положение в пространстве. Если бы было возможно все сделать достаточно точно на основе тех же датчиков что в телефоне - они бы это сделали потому что это дешевле чем создавать док-станции еще в первой версии :)

Чисто в теории ты можешь расчитывать ускорение, скорость, повороты телефона в пространстве на основе тех датчиков, а на практике... ты вряд ли получишь то что желаешь без проблем с лагами, неточными поворотами и подобными проблемами даже если напишешь это на достаточно высоком уровне. Примером являются VR на телефоне - если бы ты попробовал - увидел что иногда изображение сьезжает в сторону, иногда не точно поворачивает за головой и подобные проблемы. Иногда работает стабильно.
(Хотя, возможно, такой точности тебе будет достаточно)

Я уверен, даже, что кто-то это уже пробовал до тебя. Поищи какие-то гитхаб репозитории.

Но реально хороших результатов ты вряд ли достигнешь. Тем более, не на каждом телефоне.

Еще, возможно, тебе будет полезной смежная тема: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572837/Определение-движения-телефона-в-пространстве/574156#574156](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572837/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5/574156#574156)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!