# Двигать объекты телефоном

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу реализовать следующее: некоторому объекту (допустим, кубу) вешается скрипт. Когда игра запускается, изначальные положение и ориентация куба ассоциируются с изначальными положением и ориентацией телефона, который подключен через `unity remote`. Двигая телефон в реальной жизни на некоторый вектор `v`, я хочу, чтобы куб также двинулся в игровом мире на этот вектор. (Короче, аля контроллер `Oculus Touch`) В голову сразу пришли слова по типу акселерометр и гироскоп.

Пользуя код из документации `unity`, я пришёл к выводу, что я управляю кубом не перемещая телефон, а наклоняя его. Это мне не подходит. Как я могу реализовать мою идею?

Код из документации:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Move object using accelerometer
    float speed = 10.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

        // we assume that device is held parallel to the ground
        // and Home button is in the right hand

        // remap device acceleration axis to game coordinates:
        //  1) XY plane of the device is mapped onto XZ plane
        //  2) rotated 90 degrees around Y axis
        dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y;
        dir.z = Input.acceleration.x;

        // clamp acceleration vector to unit sphere
        if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            dir.Normalize();

        // Make it move 10 meters per second instead of 10 meters per frame...
        dir *= Time.deltaTime;

        // Move object
        transform.Translate(dir * speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

детального ответа тебе вряд ли кто даст.

Но если в двух словах - ты можешь ориентироватся или как ты сам понял по гироскопу - или по камере(AR) или комбинированно - и то и другое.

Только тебе нужно привязыватся не к прямым значениям гироскопа которые дает тебе юнити, а расчитывать математически то что тебе нужно.

Гироскоп тебе дает ускорение, на что тебе намекает слово acceleration. В твоем случае тебе нужно вспоминать физику за 7ой класс и высчитывать вектор перемещения на каждом FixedUpdate по значениям ускорения по каждому из векторов имея входные данные как ускорение. Гугли по "Равноускоренное движение по прямой растояние".
Формально у тебя между каждым FixedUpdate будет такой расчет.

Задачу с камерой ты не потянешь. Как и комбинированную.

---

Но есть еще один нюанс - ты не отличишь движение для передвижения куба от просто движения телефоном. С этим нужно что-то придумывать. Вполне вероятно что тебе будет полезно почитать вот эту ссылочку: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572837/Определение-движения-телефона-в-пространстве/574156#574156](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572837/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5/574156#574156)

Вобщем, развлекайся.